# Plot in a loop?

Tags: plotting, meta-programming

I have a list of objects, which I can plot manually:

```
one   = MapThread[{#, 1 #}&, {Range[0, 5]}];
two   = MapThread[{#, 2 #}&, {Range[0, 5]}];
three = MapThread[{#, 3 #}&, {Range[0, 5]}];

ListLinePlot[
  {
    Legended[ Symbol["one"],   "one"   ],
    Legended[ Symbol["two"],   "two"   ],
    Legended[ Symbol["three"], "three" ]
  }
]
```

I'm looking for a way to plot the same in a loop:

```
ListLinePlot[
  MapThread[Legended[ Symbol[#], # ]&, {"one", "two", "three"}]
]
```

However, this does not work.

Comment: Just use `Map` instead of `MapThread`.: `ListLinePlot[Map[Legended[Symbol[#], #] &, {"one", "two", "three"}]]`.

Comment: Btw., `Map` also suffices for constructing the data: `one = Map[{#, 1 #} &, Range[0, 5]];
two = Map[{#, 2 #} &, Range[0, 5]];
three = Map[{#, 3 #} &, Range[0, 5]];`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Indeed!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, can you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Turning a comment into an answer.*

Just use `Map` instead of `MapThread`:

```
ListLinePlot[Map[Legended[Symbol[#], #] &, {"one", "two", "three"}]]
```

Indeed, `Map` also suffices for constructing the data:

```
one = Map[{#, 1 #} &, Range[0, 5]]; 
two = Map[{#, 2 #} &, Range[0, 5]]; 
three = Map[{#, 3 #} &, Range[0, 5]];
```

`MapThread` is meant only for functions in several variables that are supposed to be fed from arguments stored in several lists. Of course, you can also use `MapThread`, but you would have to add another pair of braces in order to match `MapThread`'s syntax:

```
ListLinePlot[MapThread[Legended[Symbol[#], #] &, {{"one", "two", "three"}}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
data = Table[{#, i #} & /@ Range[0, 5], {i, 3}];

ListLinePlot[data, PlotLegends -> {"one", "two", "three"}]
```

> [image: figure plotted]

Comment: The data points in the question are not real. The real ones are much more complex. The crucial thing remains the same: to generate `Legended` invocations. `PlotLegends` are much more complex as well (involving string interpolation).

Comment: @Adobe So you need to provide a small part of the real data, yet keeping the full data structure.